# Swift3: UITableViewCell and UIButton - Show and hide UITableViewCell by clicking the UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, swift3, xcode8

I'm pretty new to `Swift 3.0` and am currently working on a school project on IOS app.

I'm having difficulties with the linkage of the `UITableViewCell` and `UIButton`.

[This is how my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwmAH.png)

Basically, what I'm trying to do is that when I click the UIButton, it will decrease the height of cells (Diary and Trend) to 0 (to hide the cells)
and 
increase the height of cells (Share and How to use the BP Monitor)(to show the cells) - assuming that the cells (Share and How to use the BP Monitor) are 'hidden' now.

Appreciate if there's an example to follow.

Thank you very much :)

*After trying the example given by @Sandeep Bhandari

This is the code in my ViewController:

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var expandedCellIndex : IndexPath? = nil

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell! = nil
    if indexPath == expandedCellIndex {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandedCell") as! ExpandedTableViewCell
        (cell as! ExpandedTableViewCell).label1.text = "shown"
        (cell as! ExpandedTableViewCell).label2.text = "Efgh"
        (cell as! ExpandedTableViewCell).label3.text = "xyz"
    }
    else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "simpleCell") as! SimpleTableViewCell
        (cell as! SimpleTableViewCell).label.text = "abcd"
    }
    return cell
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.expandedCellIndex == indexPath {
        self.expandedCellIndex = nil
    }
    else {
        self.expandedCellIndex = indexPath
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I couldn't get the same output as the answer suggested.

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwmAH.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: What problem you are facing? and you can increase the height of row as per your requirement

Comment: yes you can do it

Comment: Implement height for row at indexPath, on tapping button ask the tableView to reload. in Height for row at index path return height based on button state

Comment: Would you like to expand cell? If only increase height you can set a parameter and when you click button, that param sets height of Cell

Comment: @TinuDahiya my problem is that i'm not sure how to code the part when the button is clicked and it will call the function to increase the height of the cells.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari do you have any examples? i'm not rly sure what you mean by that

Comment: @GouravJoshi do you have any examples? i'm not very sure what do you mean by that..

Comment: @Meebfel actually My question is, what is flow of your app or viewcontroller? and where you got stuck? Because this is simple things, you just face this problem only first time not later.

Comment: @Meebfel Do you want to do like this ?https://www.dropbox.com/s/zedbmuqsmynx5zn/Untitled.mov?dl=0

Comment: @TinuDahiya Hi, i'm so sorry that my question isn't specific enough. I've edited my question. The flow of my app is when i run the app, this screenshot is just a sidemenu.

Comment: @Jecky Yes! I want to do something like that! :) Do you have examples? :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Its in my project but in swift 2.2 not in swift 3 so, I can guide on this

Comment: @Meebfel what about Trend option? How it behave in both conditions?

Comment: @Jecky Sure!! Please guide me on this! :)

Comment: @Jecky Do you have the source code from that example? :) I still can't find the answer to my problem..

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy what's a trend option?

Comment: @Meebfel its little bit long and to much to do, So how can I show you ?

Comment: @Jecky Is it possible that you send me the source code? by email.

Comment: @Meebfel I have code into swift 2.2 So I have to make one demo into swift 3.0 and I am not free now .So If I am free sure will contact you and make you demo

Comment: @Jecky oh alright.. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Meebfel Are you felicia lim ?

Comment: @Jecky yes. i'm the one who comment on your dropbox video.

Comment: @Meebfel How would you contact me for your issue ?

Comment: @Jecky via email? :) my email is: felicialiying@gmail.com

Comment: @Meebfel ok then come to hangout in gmail, I will send you req accept it

Comment: @Meebfel now I hope you probably got any helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code which will not only allow you to expand specific cell you can expand all the cell. In case you want to expand only one cell you can do that as well.

**Step 1:**

Declare two dynamic prototype cells in storyboard.
[image]

Lets call the red one as SimpleCell and Green one as ExpandedCell.

**Step 2:**

Add reusable identifier for each cell.

[image]

[image]

**Step 3**

Create custom classes for both these cells and created IBOutlets to labels.

**Step 4:**

Now write this in ViewDidLoad of your VC.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    }
```

**Step 5:**

Assuming there can only be one cell expanded at a time I am declaring single IndexPathVariable you can always declare array if you want multiple cells expanded.

```
var expandedCellIndex : IndexPath? = nil
```

**Step 6:**

Write tableView data source code.

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell! = nil
    if indexPath == expandedCellIndex {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandedCell") as! ExpandedTableViewCell
        (cell as! ExpandedTableViewCell).label1.text = "abcd"
        (cell as! ExpandedTableViewCell).label2.text = "Efgh"
        (cell as! ExpandedTableViewCell).label3.text = "xyz"
    }
    else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "simpleCell") as! SimpleTableViewCell
        (cell as! SimpleTableViewCell).label.text = "abcd"
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Step 7:**

I am expanding cell on cell tap you can do it on button tap as well :) write this logic in IBAction of button lemme write it in didSelectRow.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.expandedCellIndex == indexPath {
        self.expandedCellIndex = nil
    }
    else {
        self.expandedCellIndex = indexPath
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Conclusion :**

[image]

[image]

**Disclaimer**

I am using Dynamic cell height hence has not written heightForRowAtIndexPath as height of the cell will be automatically calculated.

If you are using any UIComponents in cell which does not have implicit size, you might have to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath as below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.expandedCellIndex == indexPath {
        return expnadedCellHeight
    }
    else {
        return simpleCellHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! For my codes, i didn't use prototype cells.. Will this answer work for non-prototype cells?

Comment: What do you mean by you dont use prototype cells ?? You must be having cell either in tableview or you must be having xibs for cell Anyway in all the cases it works :)

Comment: I've tried your answer and i couldn't get the 3 labels the in green cells to show.

Comment: where can i share the code? i can't paste it in the comment as it's too long.

Comment: Edit your question buddy and paste only important methods like delegates of tableview your logic to find which button tapped and then where are you reloading tableview stuff like that :D

Comment: ok thats the issue. See I have used dynamic height for cells. In order for them to dynamically calculate the size of the cells, you have to apply auto layout properly. Because you have not added them properly, tableview still shows the cell with height of 140 px which you set in estimatedCell height

Comment: Now I can't teach you auto layout completely, hence Ill tell you a work around, comment
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140 in viewDidLoad and implement func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { as I have shown in disclaimer of my answer :) and in if conditions return the height of cells in normal and expanded state :) you can see this height in your xib. Normal cell height and expanded cell height :D

Comment: @SandeepBhandari hi sandeep your step by step explanation is really very appreciated have a question dude what if the data comes from the API ? will you please update the code for this? coz in my case datasource for the greencolor cells would be a different API for every cell and on the click of button i have to pass all the selected cell data to server dont know how to do this :( will you please help me out? It would be great help.