# Add and remove view on cell selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview that displays some data in each cell, when the cell is selected it should expand and display more data. I have the basics of the code in but when the cell is selected the data doesn't show until another cell is selected. And the data seems to be duplicating itself into the other cells when selected. I'm sure I just need to move the calling of methods around and despite think I've tried all the combinations I can't find a solution. Heres the code that i think matters:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let answers = questions[indexPath.row].answers?.allObjects as! [Answer]
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectedDataTableViewCell

    switch selectedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        cell.contentView.viewWithTag(indexPath.row + 1)?.removeFromSuperview()
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! as IndexPath == indexPath {
            addAnswerViews(cell: cell, answers: answers, index: indexPath.row + 1)
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            cell.contentView.viewWithTag(indexPath.row + 1)?.removeFromSuperview()
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}

func addAnswerViews(cell: CollectedDataTableViewCell, answers: [Answer], index: Int) {

    var extra = CGFloat(0)
    var percentage: Double = 0

    let percentFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    percentFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    percentFormatter.multiplier = 100
    percentFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
    percentFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    answers.forEach { answer in
        let height = self.height - 6
        let width = cell.contentView.frame.width
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height + extra, width: width, height: height))
        view.tag = index

        let answerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: width - 30, height: height/2))
        answerLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        answerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        answerLabel.text = answer.text

        if answer.timesSelected == 0 || answer.timesSelectedCorrectly == 0 {

            percentage = 0
        } else {

            percentage = Double(answer.timesSelectedCorrectly)/Double(answer.timesSelected)
        }

        var percentString = percentFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: percentage))
        if percentage == 1.0 { percentString = "100%"}
        if percentage == 0.0 { percentString = "0%" }

        let timesSelectedCorrectlyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: height/2, width: width/2 - 15, height: height/2))
        timesSelectedCorrectlyLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        timesSelectedCorrectlyLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        timesSelectedCorrectlyLabel.text = "Times selected correctly: \(answer.timesSelectedCorrectly) - \(percentString!)"

        let timesSelectedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: width/2 - 15, y: height/2, width: width/2 - 15, height: height/2))
        timesSelectedLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        timesSelectedLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        timesSelectedLabel.text = "Times selected: \(answer.timesSelected)"

        view.addSubview(answerLabel)
        view.addSubview(timesSelectedCorrectlyLabel)
        view.addSubview(timesSelectedLabel)

        cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
        extra += height
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to reload UItableview section, those you want to expand.

Comment: im doing this on the second last line in didSelectRow

Comment: Also you need to set => func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return elements.count
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your didselectRowAtIndexPath as below :)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let answers = questions[indexPath.row].answers?.allObjects as! [Answer]
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectedDataTableViewCell

    if self.previouslySelectedIndexPath != nil {
        cell.contentView.viewWithTag(previouslySelectedIndexPath.row + 1)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    addAnswerViews(cell: cell, answers: answers, index: indexPath.row + 1)

    if self.previouslySelectedIndexPath != nil {
       tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath,self.previouslySelectedIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
    else {
       tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
    self.previouslySelectedIndexPath = indexPath
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: i dont have a 'previouslySelectedIndexPath' should i be setting it to nil when initialised?

Comment: Declare a variable as var previouslySelectedIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil

Comment: i just did this and get an error when selecting a cell because `previouslySelectedIndexPath` is nil at `        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath,self.previouslySelectedIndexPath as! IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)`

Comment: @wayne-rumble : Here you go buddy :) I updated my code :) please handle all edge cases, this is not a working code I wrote it just to give u an idea :)

Comment: thanks, im still getting the same issue though as the views dont appear when the cell is tapped initially, they actually flash up briefly when the cell is collapsing

Comment: @wayne-rumble : I had answered earlier similar question :) have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298578/swift3-uitableviewcell-and-uibutton-show-and-hide-uitableviewcell-by-clicking/41299270#41299270 The way you are adding view to cell is wrong :) I thought its already working hence did not wrote anything about it. The answer above explains expanding and collapsing cells in tableView :)

Comment: i have implemented your code from the link and it works so much better, but the selected cell disappears upon selection, it displays the expanded cell fine though. I have had to use my above `addAnswerViews` method to display the expanded cell contents in `cellForRowAt` any ideas?

Comment: @wayne-rumble : Hey buddy, selected cell disappears because I have replaced selected cell with expanded cell :) If you want to show old cell as well expanded cell 2 solutions 1. Insert a new cell (expanded cell) below selected cell and reload or 2. Simply create a view inside expanded cell itself which looks like original cell :) (simpler and perfectly no issue solution)